# What is coordinate format on QGIS georeferencing

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I watch tutorial from this video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THRa2OHpL0k`, and found the coordinate from the image are about 7 digits number.

> e.g. N8352000, N8356500, E247500, etc

I want to recreate what in the video did, but I only have a `degree minute second` coordinate.

> e.g. 0°30'0" N, 128°30'0"E, etc

What is the coordinate system from the video? And how to change my degree coordinate to be like in the video. I think I'll try to do it in EPSG 2857 Pseudo Mercator, if that'll be in concern while converting it.

Comment: the one in the video doesn't really matter - yours is EPSG:4326

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks, just found the converter on the internet. works well

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the video at about 1:40 the EPSG used here is 24879, but as @Ian Turton points out, that does not mean, that yours should be the same. To change the coordinates in your system you have to go to Transormation Paramters (via settings in the Georeferencer) and set the Target SRS to the correct SRS (what ever your data have).